# Matlab Plotting more that 2 y axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 3 lines on a plot, each with massively different unit scales. I would like to plot 1 yaxis left and 2 yaxis on the right side, currently I just reduced the one line's value by a factor. Also in the future I would like to have 2  axis on one side to maybe display SI units and empirical for a single line. Currently im using `yyaxis left` and `yyaxis right` for the left and right yaxis

Can matlab add 2 axis on one side?
How to do it?

Edit: If not, what shenanigans can achieve the same result?

[image: Want something like this, other axis values too]

Comment: I think MATLAB cannot do that. Regardless of whether MATLAB can do that, why would you want to do this? If the units/scales are so different, comparing actual values in a single plot makes not much sense, unless you do it in a heuristic way (Line A goes up when line B goes down), in which case I'd recommend just normalising all data to `(0 1)` and make the axis units "arbitrary" and add a legend to the plot mentioning what line does what.

Comment: @Adriaan Does not solve my problem, BUT you solved a problem within the figure. This graph is for heuristic inspection and normalizing the data to between zero and one is a great idea, so very thanks for that. Regarding the 2 axis on one side is of importance since people want to see things in the units they want. One can use the same axis and apply a scalar to a value but now the person reading the graph has to think, divide or multiply by the scalar. People don't like thinking, the double axis is an attempt to simplify data and not overwhelm the person with large amount of different graphs

Comment: Then I'd go for the three normalised normalised lines, and add the units (if you really want) in the legend. Or better just give them descriptive names in the legend, and add the units in the caption, mentioning they are normalised. I'd say having a single figure with 3 axis in different units is rather confusing in itself, and requires more thinking than e.g. 3 subplots.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with @Adriaan here. Multiple axes in the same plot are confusing, it is better to have multiple plots or bring all data into same units (e.g. fractional change since t=0). I find it funny that you say “people are lazy” and then want to make it harder to read the graph... :)

Comment: apparently its possible, I just dont know whats going on with the code discussed.[link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/177412/image.jpeg)  [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101806-how-can-i-insert-my-matlab-figure-fig-files-into-multiple-subplots)

Comment: For the display of a scale with both unit system (SI and Imperial), you can just display one curve, one yaxis for it, and only modify the `YTickLabels` so they show the values in both unit system.